# Passing a Variable from PHP to Javascript for Image file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a gallery of images.  When a user clicks on an image, the page scrolls and displays the image along with a Title, Description, and a "Go to" button.  All works great except passing a variable for the Go To button.  I need to pass the user ID to the JS script.   Here is the partial PHP code:

```
<img src=<?php echo $image_finder?>
 height=<?php echo $img_height?> 
 width=<?php echo $img_width?>     
 class="superbox-img" 
 data-img="<?php echo $image_finder?>" 
 title="<?php echo $artist_name?>" 
 alt="<?php echo $artist_about ?>" 
 location="<?php echo $artist_id?>" >
```

The PHP code is in a foreach loop.  There may be a hundred images but I need to get the ID (in the location parameter) for the selected image.

At the bottom of the PHP page, I include the JS file and the following call to the JS file and function.

```
 var pagefunction = function() {
    $('.superbox').SuperBox();

};

loadScript("js/plugin/superbox/superbox.min.js", pagefunction);
```

In the JS file, I need to get the location parameter and pass into the HREF.  I have marked where the variable need to go about 8 lines down after the main.php?location=(variable).  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks, Grant

```
    function(a) {
    a.fn.SuperBox = function() {
        var b = a('<div class="superbox-show"></div>'),
            c = a('<img src="" class="superbox-current-img">
                <div id="imgInfoBox" class="superbox-imageinfo inline-block"> 
                <h1>Image Title</h1>
                <span><p><em>http://imagelink.com/thisimage.jpg</em></p>
                <p class="superbox-img-description">Image description</p>
                <p><a **href="main.php?location=' + location + '**" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Go to    Artist</a> 
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a></p></span> </div>'),
            d = a('<div class="superbox-close txt-color-white"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i></div>');
            b.append(c).append(d);
            a(".superbox-imageinfo");
                return this.each(function() {
            a(".superbox-list").click(function() {
                $this = a(this);
        var d = $this.find(".superbox-img"),
                    e = d.data("img"),
                    f = d.attr("alt") || "No description",
                    g = e,
                    h = d.attr("title") || "No Title";
                    l = d.attr("location") || "No Location";
                c.attr("src", e), a(".superbox-list").removeClass("active"),   $this.addClass("active"), c.find("em").text(g), c.find(">:first-child").text(h), c.find(".superbox-img-description").text(f), 0 == a(".superbox-current-img").css("opacity") && a(".superbox-current-img").animate({
                    opacity: 1
                }), a(this).next().hasClass("superbox-show") ? (a(".superbox-list").removeClass("active"), b.toggle()) : (b.insertAfter(this).css("display", "block"), $this.addClass("active")), a("html, body").animate({
                    scrollTop: b.position().top - d.width()
                }, "medium")
            }), a(".superbox").on("click", ".superbox-close", function() {
                a(".superbox-list").removeClass("active"), a(".superbox-current-img").animate({
                    opacity: 0
                }, 200, function() {
                    a(".superbox-show").slideUp()
                })
            })
        })
    }
}(jQuery);
```

Comment: I edited my description to provide more information.  Not working with the suggestions provided.  Any additional information is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**SEMICOLONS!**

```
<img src=<?php echo $image_finder; ?> height=<?php echo $img_height; ?> width=<?php echo $img_width; ?>     class="superbox-img" data-img="<?php echo $image_finder; ?>" title="<?php echo $artist_name; ?>" alt="<?php echo $artist_about; ?>" location="<?php echo $artist_id; ?>" >
```

*EDIT*
**QUOTES!**

```
<img src="<?php echo $image_finder; ?>" height="<?php echo $img_height; ?>" width="<?php echo $img_width; ?>" class="superbox-img" data-img="<?php echo $image_finder; ?>" title="<?php echo $artist_name; ?>" alt="<?php echo $artist_about; ?>" location="<?php echo $artist_id; ?>" >
```

Comment: EXCITEMENT! BOLD TEXT!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

Put your javascript code in the PHP page and echo the variable value, ie:

```
c = a('<img src="" class="superbox-current-img">
        <div id="imgInfoBox" class="superbox-imageinfo inline-block"> 
        <h1>Image Title</h1>
        <span><p><em>http://imagelink.com/thisimage.jpg</em></p>
        <p class="superbox-img-description">Image description</p>
        <p><a href="main.php?location=<?php echo urlencode($variable) ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Go to    Artist</a> 
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a></p></span> </div>'),
    d = a('<div class="superbox-close txt-color-white"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i></div>');
```

**Solution 2:**

In you JS file do something like

```
var MYAPP = MYAPP || (function(){
var _vars = {};

return {
    init : function(variables) {
        _vars = variables;
        // ... you other code
    },
    superBox : function() {
        //.. your other code
        c = a('<img src="" class="superbox-current-img">
        <div id="imgInfoBox" class="superbox-imageinfo inline-block"> 
        <h1>Image Title</h1>
        <span><p><em>http://imagelink.com/thisimage.jpg</em></p>
        <p class="superbox-img-description">Image description</p>
        <p><a href="main.php?location=' + _args.yourVariable + '" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Go to    Artist</a> 
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a></p></span> </div>'),
    d = a('<div class="superbox-close txt-color-white"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i></div>');
        //.. your other code
    }
};
}());
```

then in your php file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   MYAPP.init({myVariable: "<?php echo urlencode($myVariable) ?>"});
   MYAPP.superBox();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't able to get it to work so I edited my original post to add more information.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks